# So how can we protect our PHP application scripts when installing locally for a client?

Tags: php

Question:
There should always be a way to protect your intellectual PHP application when you are running/installing it locally for the client unlike it be cloud or SAAS application on your own server.

Is there a tool that can encrypt the entire software application and still run perfectly locally or even in the cloud?

I have tried tools like; PHPLockIt,
https://www.phplockit.com/

PHPLockIt works fine but I later realized it can be decrypted on this site:
https://www.unphp.net/

So how can we protect our PHP application scripts when installing locally for a client?

Comment: I believe https://www.ioncube.com/ is the standard.  I googled alternatives to ioncube and found phpbolt and sourceguardian.

Comment: phplockit seems not functional, my page with only `phpinfo();` was not show correctly after encrypting it.  (and unphp.net was unable to decrypt it....)   Did you actually test those products before spamming them here? 

Comment: @Alan your recommendations look pretty and phpbolt is okay for now... would try it out, I love the fact is open source and we can contribute to it.

Comment: @Luuk can you explain further what you meant? I know phplockit is functional in encrypting the code but can be decrypted on unphp.

Comment: I created a php-file with the 2 lines `<?php` and `phpinfo();`, and did select 'Encoding' and 'Obfuscation' in  `PHP-Lockit!`. when opening the result i got: `Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in D:\PHP LockIt Demo\Output\phpinfo.php on line 1`   (tested with PHP 8.0.10, on Windows)

Comment: I must have missed this on the [features](http://www.phplockit.com/index.php) of PHPLockit: "Works with any installation of PHP 4, PHP 5 or PHP 6."  

Comment: @Alan have you tried the phpbolt yourself? Looks like the encrypt function is not seeing my extension. Im getting "Call to undefined function bolt_encrypt() " meanwhile I have added the extension "php_bolt.dll" to the path "C:\xampp\php\ext" and enable it in the php.ini? Any comments/help?

Comment: I have not used that, sorry.  I have only used ioncube, and only as a user of a php library that was encrypted.